# Updating all rows in a group with maximum value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have researched & tried to solve this, but can't get through this. Please pardon me if this seems a simple one
I have a dataset like below :-

[image]

I want to update all the rows for columns Inspection_Date and Sl_No as the latest within a gro
up of SFID.

The resulting table should look like below :-

[image]

I have tried it in two ways:-

Help Source :- help from this [sqlite: update all rows in group with value from first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307056/sqlite-update-all-rows-in-group-with-value-from-first-row)

Code 1:-

```
UPDATE new_copy_2 set Sl_No = (
    SELECT MAX(Sl_No) as max_date
    FROM new_copy_2 T2
    where Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%'
   and exists 
       (select 1 from new_copy_2 tt
         where tt.SFID  = T2.SFID
           and tt.Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%')
```

Error :-

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Help Source :- [MySQL - updating all records to match max value in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075140/mysql-updating-all-records-to-match-max-value-in-group)

Code 2:-

```
UPDATE new_copy_2
JOIN  (
        SELECT  SFID, MAX(Sl_No) AS flag
        FROM    new_copy_2
        GROUP BY
                SFID
        ) t
ON      SFID = t.SFID
SET     Sl_No = t.flag
where Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%'
   and exists 
       (select 1 from new_copy_2 tt
         where tt.SFID  = SFID
           and tt.Inspection_Type like '%PMCR%')
```

Error:-

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.
Incorrect syntax near 't'.
```

Please Help !!

Input data set example

```
|  : Inspection_Date : | : SFID          : | Sl_No
|  : 7/4/2020        : | : SF-0000000HYD : | 8868
|  : 6/4/2020        : | : SF-0000000HYD : | 8864
|  : 3/3/2020        : | : SF-0000836659 : | 7845
|  : 3/1/2020        : | : SF-0000836659 : | 7842
|  : 4/7/2020        : | : SF-0000836432 : | 7862
|  : 4/5/2020        : | : SF-0000836432 : | 7840
```

Expected data set example

```
|:   Inspection_Date |: SFID          |: Sl_No
|:   7/4/2020        |: SF-0000000HYD |: 8868
|:   7/4/2020        |: SF-0000000HYD |: 8868
|:   3/3/2020        |: SF-0000836659 |: 7845
|:   3/3/2020        |: SF-0000836659 |: 7845
|:   4/7/2020        |: SF-0000836432 |: 7862
|:   4/7/2020        |: SF-0000836432 |: 7862
```

Comment: Please share table structures and some sample data if you can.

Comment: I have included the input table & the required resulting data table

Comment: those are images. If you could provide some data in text format  I could have been able to verify the query before answering. That's why i asked.

Comment: @ Kazi :- I have added the sample of both input dataset & expected result data set. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

you can try cte with window function as below:

```
 with cte as (
select *, max(sl_no)over (partition by sfid order by  Inspection_Date desc) MaxSL
from new_copy_2 )
update cte set sl_no=MaxSL
where sl_no <> maxsl;
```

I am afraid it's not possible to update an identity column in sql server but you can insert the new rows by setting identitty_insert on and then delete the existing rows. Check below link.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155775/how-to-update-identity-column-in-sql-server#:~:text=You%20can%20not%20update%20identity,a%20similar%20kind%20of%20requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155775/how-to-update-identity-column-in-sql-server#:%7E:text=You%20can%20not%20update%20identity,a%20similar%20kind%20of%20requirement).

Comment: I would also add `where sl_no <> max_sl`.  SQL Server is more efficient when it doesn't update rows with no changes.

Comment: Error :-          
              Cannot update identity column 'Sl_No'.

Comment: @r_sh_07 . . . Your question is about updating that column.  If it is an identity, then you can't do it.

Comment: The Inspection Date for Highest serial number is also always the highest in a group and highest serial number always has latest date. Can we not use both as identity column for each other ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sub-query as follows:

```
UPDATE new_copy_2 set Sl_No = (
    SELECT MAX(Sl_No) as max_date
    FROM new_copy_2 T2
    where sfid = T2.sfid)
   where exists 
       (select 1 from new_copy_2 tt
         where tt.SFID  = SFID)
```

Comment: :- It says 
             Cannot update identity column 'Sl_No'.

Comment: :- Same error using this too
           Cannot update identity column 'Sl_No'.

Comment: Same error   :- Cannot update identity column 'Sl_No'.

Answer (score 0):

I Could solve it using a workaround by first extracting the rows for maximum of Sl_No within each SFID & then matching the extracted table with original table. Below is the code for the same, where trial_data_extract is the maximum rows extracted & trial_data is the original data.

```
Select * into trial_data_extract from trial_data AS dat1
where Sl_No =
        ( Select MAX(Sl_No) from trial_data As dat2 where dat1.SFID =dat2.SFID)

Update trial_data 
Set Identifier = dat2.Identifier, 
    Inspection_Date = dat2.Inspection_Date 
from trial_data dat1 
Inner Join 
trial_data_extract dat2
on dat1.SFID = dat2.SFID
```

Thank you everyone for the help !!